# merge statement using ROWID

Tags: plsql, merge, lookup

I have 3 foreign dimension keys I need to populate on a fact table.  I have tried using the following merge statement (using ROWID) to populate these three fields, however it is taking over 15 hours to run, so I am wondering what alternative approaches I can take that will be faster?  The fact table is around 1.8 million records and one of the dimensions (lookup function 3) is 900K records.

I have created 3 lookup functions to return the dimension keys.  Each of these functions goes from a field on the fact table and has to join to 2 or 3 tables to return the dim keys.  I have indexed the fields in the joins and the explain plan for each of them looks reasonable however it is still taking an extremely long time to run.  I am going to need to re-populate these dim keys each time the data is refreshed because unfortunately the source data is truncated and reloaded each time.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
MERGE INTO 
(SELECT PRODUCT_DIM_KEY, TERRITORY_DIM_KEY, ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY , CUST_ID , PD_DT, DEXCOM_SKU_CD, ROWID rid 
FROM FACT_TABLE
) ft1
USING (select ROWID as rid
FROM FACT_TABLE
 ) ft2
ON (ft1.rid = ft2.rid)
--join using ROWID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET ft1.PRODUCT_DIM_KEY  = PRODUCT_DIM_LOOKUP_FUNCTION(ft1.DEXCOM_SKU_CD),
--lookup function 1
ft1.TERRITORY_DIM_KEY = TERRITORY_DIM_LOOKUP_FUNCTION(ft1.CUST_ID ),
--lookup function 2
ft1.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY = ACCOUNT_DIM_LOOKUP_FUNCTION(ft1.CUST_ID)
--lookup function 3
```

--Lookup function 1
--columns indexed: pr.PRODUCT_SKU

```
BEGIN
    SELECT PRODUCT_DIM_KEY INTO v_dim_id
    FROM   PRODUCT_DIM pr 
    WHERE  pr.PRODUCT_SKU          = p_product_code
    AND    pr.PRODUCT_DELETED_FLAG = 'N';
```

--Lookup function 2
--columns indexed: addr.EXTRNL_CUST_ID, addr.PSTL_CD

```
BEGIN
    SELECT TERRITORY_DIM_KEY
  INTO v_dim_id
  FROM ADDR_DIM addr,
       ZIP_CODE_DIM zip,
       TERRITORY_DIM terr
 WHERE     p_hcp_code = addr.EXTRNL_CUST_ID
       AND addr.BEST_REC_IND = 1
       AND SUBSTR (addr.PSTL_CD, 1, 5) = zip.ZIP_CODE
       AND zip.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
       AND terr.TERRITORY_CODE = zip.TERRITORY_CODE;
```

--Lookup function 3
--columns indexed: ccv.VAL_1_ID, ac.IMS_ID, ac.ACTIVE_FLAG

```
BEGIN
SELECT ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
  INTO v_dim_id
  FROM CCV_DIM ccv, 
       ACCOUNT_DIM ac
 WHERE     p_hcp_code = ccv.CUST_ID
       AND ccv.SCNDY_ID_TYP_XID = 202325
       AND ccv.VAL_1_ID = ac.IMS_ID
       AND ac.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a `MERGE` here. You've only got code on the `WHEN MATCHED` branch so you can just use an UPDATE. Also - this statement updates every single row of your fact table, which means you're making 5.4 million procedure calls (3 * 1.8 million) and 1.8 million row updates. Was that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PL/SQL functions. You avoid [context switch](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/plsql-stop-making-the-same-performance-mistakes) overhead.
Just do a simple update using correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE FACT_TABLE ft1
SET 
ft1.PRODUCT_DIM_KEY = (
     SELECT PRODUCT_DIM_KEY FROM   PRODUCT_DIM pr 
     WHERE  pr.PRODUCT_SKU          = ft1.DEXCOM_SKU_CD
       AND    pr.PRODUCT_DELETED_FLAG = 'N'
),
ft1.TERRITORY_DIM_KEY = (
        SELECT TERRITORY_DIM_KEY  
        FROM ADDR_DIM addr, ZIP_CODE_DIM zip, TERRITORY_DIM terr
        WHERE     ft1.CUST_ID = addr.EXTRNL_CUST_ID
          AND addr.BEST_REC_IND = 1
          AND SUBSTR (addr.PSTL_CD, 1, 5) = zip.ZIP_CODE
          AND zip.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
          AND terr.TERRITORY_CODE = zip.TERRITORY_CODE
),
ft1.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY = (
         SELECT ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
         FROM CCV_DIM ccv, ACCOUNT_DIM ac
         WHERE     ft1.CUST_ID = ccv.CUST_ID
           AND ccv.SCNDY_ID_TYP_XID = 202325
           AND ccv.VAL_1_ID = ac.IMS_ID
           AND ac.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' 
)
```

I belive it will be at least 40~50 times faster 
--> yes, 50 times, it's not a mistake - 50 times it is 5000% !!!
1 hour instead of 50 hours.